# PowerShell - Weather WebService

Tags: web-services, powershell, openweathermap

I want to use PowerShell to query a Web Service and ask for the weather in my city (Hamburg, Germany) for a demo.

I found the following URL and script from 2011. But this Web Service is not working anymore.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

https://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/15/retrieving-weather-information-from-a-web-service-provider/

```
$a = New-WebServiceProxy 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' 
$a.GetWeather('San Francisco','United States')
```

**Response:** No Data

Comment: What about OpenWeatherAPI? See here for exmaple: http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Get-Weather_cmdlet_for_PowerShell,_using_the_OpenWeatherMap_API

Comment: Thanks. I know this site but I want to use the build-in features.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [OpenWeather](https://openweathermap.org) and get yourself an [API](https://openweathermap.org/api) key.

[This URL](http://openweathermap.org/help/city_list.txt) has a list of all the cities. There are multiple entries. I found San Francisco's (5391959) by Googling and hit this URL:

http://openweathermap.org/city/5391959?utm_source=openweathermap&utm_medium=widget&utm_campaign=html_old

...from which I extracted the `5391959` city ID.

Armed with your API key and the city id, you can use the following two commands to get your weather in JSON format:

```
$weather = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5391959&APPID=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
$weatherObject = $weather.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$weatherObject # display to console
```

...which will give you an object, like this:

```
coord      : @{lon=-122.42; lat=37.77}
weather    : {@{id=804; main=Clouds; description=overcast clouds; icon=04n}}
base       : stations
main       : @{temp=285.91; pressure=1017; humidity=93; temp_min=283.15; temp_max=288.15}
visibility : 16093
wind       : @{speed=4.6; deg=240}
clouds     : @{all=90}
dt         : 1489134900
sys        : @{type=1; id=226; message=0.1525; country=US; sunrise=1489156026; sunset=1489198372}
id         : 5391959
name       : San Francisco
cod        : 200
```